# Compare Value in Cell to Array and then Add Value if True

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still a bit new to VBA and have been working on making my own macros and all on & off. But I have a bit of an issue with a bit of code.

I have a log that I record vendor information in to, and on the worksheet, I have this code below that searches for value entered on it via number entry and it then checks to see if a name is affiliated to it from another worksheet containing the table of names.

The code below works fine for the most part, however, I have had a difficult time trying to get it to also search if the value entered has already been entered either above or below it. As it stands, when a number is entered, it pulls the name and then adds a value of 1 to a corresponding cell by the found result on the worksheet containing the list of names.

The end result I am trying to achieve, is to have it check if the name exists on the current worksheet (Not the sheet with the list of names), and if it does, will not add a value of 1 to the sheet containing all of my names and numbers.

I've tried using a loop but have had no success in getting it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B6:B37", "B46:B77")) Is Nothing Then

If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Target.Value) Then

   Application.EnableEvents = False

   Vendor = Sheet8.Range("A2:B500")
   Target.Value = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Vendor, 2, False)

   Application.EnableEvents = True

   Set StartValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor List").Range("A:B").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
   cPos = StartValue.Address

   Set ThisValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Wednesday").Range("B6:B77").Find(What:=Target.Value, _
            After:=Target.Value, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=True, _
            SearchFormat:=False)

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor List").Range(cPos).Offset(0, 8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor List").Range(cPos).Offset(0, 8).Value + 1

End If

If IsError(Target.Value) Then

    Target.Value = ""
    MsgBox "The Vendor number entered is not listed. Either you have entered an invalid number, or you have not yet added this vendor to the Vendor List sheet.", vbCritical
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor List").Range(cPos).Offset(0, 8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor List").Range(cPos).Offset(0, 8).Value - 1

End If

End If
```

I've attached an image of how it works. Hopefully, it clears a bit up...

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNrVq.jpg)

Comment: Is this a handler in a worksheet, or in the ThisWorkbook module?

Comment: It's a handler within a worksheet.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a 1 in the Frequency column the first time a vendor is used on the Wednesday sheet? And then you don't want that 1 to ever increase no matter how many times that vendor is used? If so, then `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor List").Range(cPos).Offset(0, 8).Value = 1` will do it.

Comment: Basically, I have a log for everyday of the week. And the purpose of having a column to record frequency, is to track delivery frequency per day and not necessarily how many times an entry is recorded by the same vendor per day. So if a vendor delivers 5 times in a week, it will show 5. There's more in the backend of my log, but am ultimately attempting to create a pivottable with the info in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const RNG_VENDOR As String = "B6:B37,B46:B77"

    Dim v, f As Range, vendor, vendorCount

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range(RNG_VENDOR)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    v = Target.Value
    If IsNumeric(v) And Len(v) > 0 Then

       'see if there's a numeric match
       Set f = Sheet8.Range("A:A").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not f Is Nothing Then
            vendor = f.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Value 'get the vendor name
            '#### edit below to fix lookup range
            vendorCount = Application.CountIf(Me.Range("B6:B77"), vendor) 'count any existing
            'update the vendors sheet?
            With f.EntireRow.Cells(1, "J")
                If vendorCount = 0 Then .Value = .Value + 1
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = vendor 'switch from vendor number to vendor name
            Application.EnableEvents = True

       Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = ""   'clear the value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            MsgBox "The Vendor number '" & v & "' entered is not listed....", vbExclamation
       End If   'was found
    End If      'is a number

End Sub
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you for your assistance. However, when recording an additional entry with the same name, it still increases the value by 1 regardless if there's multiple instances of a name.

Comment: If you use `MsgBox vendorCount` in that situation what value pops up?

Comment: Nothing happens. No message box comes up.

Comment: Well *something* should pop up if you put that Msgbox right after `vendorCount = ...`

Comment: Nothing does unfortunately.  I'll have to take a stab at it tomorrow, as my brain is fried from messing around with everything earlier.

Comment: See my edit on the `Application.Countif` line - I forgot you need to give that a single-area range to look at.  Should be OK now.

Comment: That indeed did the trick. Learned something as well from this. Thanks a million, Tim!